# Remove JSON API links in header html

Tags: themes

Does anyone know how to remove the WordPress JSON API links in the header tag?

```
<head>
...
<link rel='https://api.w.org/' href='http://example.com/wp-json/' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="http://example.com/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=..." />
<link rel="alternate" type="text/xml+oembed" href="http://example.com/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=..." />
</head>
```

I'd like to avoid using a plugin. If possible, is there a way to remove them with the remove_action function?

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'rsd_link' );
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I see in filters.php "add_action( 'wp_head', 'rest_output_link_wp_head', 10, 0 )" Which makes me think this should do the trick to remove `rel='https://api.w.org/'`.

```
remove_action( 'wp_head',      'rest_output_link_wp_head'              );
```

The rest... * *cough* * seem to be in default-filters.php

```
remove_action( 'wp_head',      'wp_oembed_add_discovery_links'         );
```

To remove the [rest_output_link_header](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_output_link_header/)

```
remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'rest_output_link_header', 11 );
```

Reference

- [wp_oembed_add_discovery_links](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_oembed_add_discovery_links/)
- [rest_output_link_wp_head](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_output_link_wp_head/)
- [rest_output_link_header](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_output_link_header/)

Comment: thanks but this does not remove the `api.w.org` link for me.

Comment: Tried all of them, but the api.w.org header won't budge! This no longer seems to work in the recent wordpress versions.

Comment: All right, it worked! Turns out you have to put this in the theme's `function.php`. I was trying to put this in my custom plugin so that it works for all themes, but apparently that doesn't work.

Answer (score 30):

This custom function should help removing all links in the header and footer - you may put it inside the `functions.php` file of your active theme;

```
function remove_json_api () {

    // Remove the REST API lines from the HTML Header
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'rest_output_link_wp_head', 10 );
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_oembed_add_discovery_links', 10 );

    // Remove the REST API endpoint.
    remove_action( 'rest_api_init', 'wp_oembed_register_route' );

    // Turn off oEmbed auto discovery.
    add_filter( 'embed_oembed_discover', '__return_false' );

    // Don't filter oEmbed results.
    remove_filter( 'oembed_dataparse', 'wp_filter_oembed_result', 10 );

    // Remove oEmbed discovery links.
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_oembed_add_discovery_links' );

    // Remove oEmbed-specific JavaScript from the front-end and back-end.
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_oembed_add_host_js' );

   // Remove all embeds rewrite rules.
   add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'disable_embeds_rewrites' );

}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_json_api' );
```

And this snippet completely disable the REST API and shows the content below when you visit `http://example.com/wp-json/`, were `example.com` is the domain name of your website;

```
{"code":"rest_disabled","message":"The REST API is disabled on this site."}
```

In order to disable WordPress REST API, use the snippet below;

```
function disable_json_api () {

  // Filters for WP-API version 1.x
  add_filter( 'json_enabled', '__return_false' );
  add_filter( 'json_jsonp_enabled', '__return_false' );

  // Filters for WP-API version 2.x
  add_filter( 'rest_enabled', '__return_false' );
  add_filter( 'rest_jsonp_enabled', '__return_false' );

}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'disable_json_api' );
```

Comment: Is it necessary to remove `wp_oembed_add_discovery_links` from the head twice with different priorities or is that a typo?

Comment: Also in the `disable_json_api()` if using the latest wordpress can we just include the version 2.x filters or are both needed?

Comment: The custom function is missing the function `disable_embeds_rewrites`. The complete source can be found at https://github.com/swissspidy/disable-embeds/blob/master/disable-embeds.php.

Comment: @Drakes Yes, you're right. It's missing it because this code hasn't been updated since it has been posted last year. Why not modify/update the snippet above to help others here instead? That would be helpful and handy ;)

Comment: I'll leave that entirely to your discretion.

Comment: I'd rather recommend to use the Disable Embeds plugin instead of copying only half of it into your plugin or theme. It's more future-proof.

Comment: `rest_enabled` is deprecated since version 4.7.0

Answer (score 4):

The best solution and easy way to disable oEmbed discovery links and wp-embed.min.js is by adding this code snippet in your theme (`function.php`).

`remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_oembed_add_discovery_links', 10 );
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_oembed_add_host_js' );
remove_action('rest_api_init', 'wp_oembed_register_route');
remove_filter('oembed_dataparse', 'wp_filter_oembed_result', 10);`

Hope this can help someone as the above solutions don't work for me while using the latest version of WordPress.