# How to remove rest api link: in http headers?

Tags: headers, http, http-api, rest-api

i would like to remove the "link:" line added to the http headers since wordpress 4.4

here is a

```
curl -I killcandida.org
```

here is the output extract of the line that i would like to delete:

```
Link: <http://killcandida.org/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
```

Note that i don't talk here about html headers but http headers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The output is generated by the rest_output_link_header(). This function is used in two actions, **wp_head** and **template_redirect** in **default-filters.php:@line234**. You can remove the function from those hooks to remove the output you wanted to remove. Put the following codes in your theme's functions.php to achieve the desired result.

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'rest_output_link_wp_head', 10);    
remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'rest_output_link_header', 11);
```

- [rest_output_link_header](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_output_link_header/)
- [Remove WordPress JSON API links in header html](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/211469/84219)

Both actions are defined in `ABSPATH/wp-includes/default-filters.php` under `// REST API filters.`

Comment: what is the original purpose of this header for? if removing it, is there any side effect to the application?

Comment: I'm sure it's to tell someone where your JSON feed is. If that's not something your application is designed to support then it's not a side effect IMHO.