# WP REST API V2 - Retrieve sub page by full slug (URL/Path)

Tags: rest-api

I'm struggling to see if this is natively supported, or if it's not the best place to implement this functionality - in my app (Laravel) or the same side as the API (WordPress).

Retrieving a single page (/about-us) via the slug is easy:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=about-us
```

But the issue comes with retrieving a sub/child page. Consider /about-us/child-page - this works perfectly fine in WordPress but retrieving the page via the Rest API seems impossible?

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=about-us/child-page
/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=%2Fabout-us%2Fchild-page%2F
```

No Results.

I can search for that individual page and get results, however if another page then shares that slug there's the potential for collisions.

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=child-page
```

There's `get_page_by_path()` which allows you to search for pages via path which is exactly what I'm after - I can implement this using a custom REST API endpoint (https://www.coditty.com/code/wordpress-rest-api-how-to-get-content-by-slug) but the returned result is not standard and not comparable to the WP-REST equivalent (See below)

```
{
    "id": 22,
    "date": "2017-03-28T13:15:53",
    "date_gmt": "2017-03-28T12:15:53",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/?page_id=22"
    },
    "modified": "2017-03-28T13:15:53",
    "modified_gmt": "2017-03-28T12:15:53",
    "slug": "test-sub-page",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "page",
    "link": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/test-sub-page/",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "Test Sub page"
    },
    "content": {
      "rendered": "...",
      "protected": false
    },
    "excerpt": {
      "rendered": "....",
      "protected": false
    },
    "author": 1,
    "featured_media": 0,
    "parent": 7,
    "menu_order": 0,
    "comment_status": "closed",
    "ping_status": "closed",
    "template": "",
    "meta": [],
    "_links": {
      "self": [
        {
          "href": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/22"
        }
      ],
      "collection": [
        {
          "href": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/wp-json/wp/v2/pages"
        }
      ],
      "about": [
        {
          "href": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/wp-json/wp/v2/types/page"
        }
      ],
      "author": [
        {
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1"
        }
      ],
      "replies": [
        {
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=22"
        }
      ],
      "version-history": [
        {
          "href": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/22/revisions"
        }
      ],
      "up": [
        {
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/7"
        }
      ],
      "wp:attachment": [
        {
          "href": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=22"
        }
      ],
      "curies": [
        {
          "name": "wp",
          "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
          "templated": true
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

VS

```
{
  "ID": 22,
  "post_author": "1",
  "post_date": "2017-03-28 13:15:53",
  "post_date_gmt": "2017-03-28 12:15:53",
  "post_content": "...",
  "post_title": "Test Sub page",
  "post_excerpt": "",
  "post_status": "publish",
  "comment_status": "closed",
  "ping_status": "closed",
  "post_password": "",
  "post_name": "test-sub-page",
  "to_ping": "",
  "pinged": "",
  "post_modified": "2017-03-28 13:15:53",
  "post_modified_gmt": "2017-03-28 12:15:53",
  "post_content_filtered": "",
  "post_parent": 7,
  "guid": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/?page_id=22",
  "menu_order": 0,
  "post_type": "page",
  "post_mime_type": "",
  "comment_count": "0",
  "filter": "raw"
}
```

Alternatively I can poll the API for each segment/page from my app to verify that each page exists and build up the data that way...

Comment: Why `/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=child-page` is a problem ? Slugs are unique, right? Maybe you can try `parent` argument but it has to be an ID. It seems to me a bit redundant to have `/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=about-us/child-page` just for the request and not for the url the users sees and will probably share or bookmark.

Comment: Thanks @Laxmana, I ended up with this solution: https://gist.github.com/Snaver/9abf24132b53b9d670bb96ab63c11e97

Comment: I think in most applications the slug would be `about/{me}` and `contact/{me}` returning posts by slug would give you two different pages.  I feel like a query by URI or GUID would be more efficient and is unique.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this functionality is not natively supported out of the box. In detail, the problem is that most post types including `page` use the base `WP_REST_Posts_Controller` which maps the `slug` parameter to the `post_name__in` `WP_Query` argument, which does not facilitate resolving hierarchical slugs. The `pagename` query variable does, however - but only one per query, which might be why it's not already leveraged for REST requests for hierarchical post types.

There are a number of solutions and work-arounds. Please note that the code below has not been thoroughly tested, and the JavaScript in particular neglects important authentication and error-handling practices - it is intended for illustrative purposes only.

---

## Make Multiple Requests

Your client can simply work through each path part and use the `_fields` parameter to minimize server load by only requesting ancestor posts' ID, then using that post ID as the `parent` argument for the subsequent request:

```js
async function wpse261645_fetchPage( path ) {
  const parts = path.split( '/' );
  const uri = '/wp-json/wp/v2/pages';
  let parent_id;

  for( let i = 0; i < parts.length; i++ ) {
    const params = new URLSearchParams( { slug: parts[i] } );

    if( i < parts.length - 1 )
      params.append( '_fields', 'id' );

    if( parent_id )
      params.append( 'parent', parent_id );
    
    const res = await fetch(
      `${uri}?${params}`,
      {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
      }
    ).then( res => res.json() );

    if( i === parts.length - 1 )
      return res;

    parent_id = res[0].id;
  }
}
```

---

## Modify `slug` REST Param/QV Mapping

This is probably the most appealing solution as it can effectively address the original issue directly without requiring special handling client-side. But it's a bit convoluted and experimental due to the number of moving parts involved and my own lack of familiarity with the REST API - I'm totally open to suggestions and improvements!

Before the `WP_REST_Posts_Controller` executes a query to retrieve the items corresponding to the request, it runs the query args and the request object through [the `rest_{$this->post_type}_query` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_query/). We can leverage this filter to selectively re-map `slug` as necessary for chosen post-types or controllers.

It's also necessary to adjust the `slug` parameter's schema, parsing and sanitization routine for the relevant controllers such that it doesn't strip out `/`s or `%2F`s from the slug value or trip validation errors. I don't *think* that this should create any compatibility issues as the only parts of the schema and parameter registration that are touched are swapping out their sanitization callbacks - the changes should be near invisible to clients and discovery, and wholly backwards-compatible with the original functionality (unless someone's been relying on the REST API to transform `/`s in slugs into `-`s) - but I haven't tested it thoroughly.

### Parsing, Schema, and Sanitization Adjustments (to keep the `/`s)

```php
function wpse261645_sanitize_nested_slug( $slug ) {
  // Exploding slugs, as one does.
  $slug_parts = array_map( 'sanitize_title', explode( '/', $slug ) );

  return implode( '/', $slug_parts );
}

function wpse261645_parse_nested_slug_list( $slugs ) {
  $slugs = wp_parse_list( $slugs );

  return array_unique( array_map( 'wpse261645_sanitize_nested_slug', $slugs ) );
}

function wpse261645_nested_slug_schema( $schema ) {
  $schema['slug']['arg_options']['sanitize_callback'] = 'wpse261645_sanitize_nested_slug';

  return $schema;
}
add_filter( 'rest_page_item_schema', 'wpse261645_nested_slug_schema' );

function wpse261645_nested_slug_collection_params( $params ) {
  $params['slug']['sanitize_callback'] = 'wpse261645_parse_nested_slug_list';

  return $params;
}
add_filter( 'rest_page_collection_params', 'wpse261645_nested_slug_collection_params' );
```

### Remapping the `slug` REST Param to Query Variables

Now that `/`s are persisted in the `slug` parameter, we can map the values into a variety of different queries:

```php
function wpse261645_remap_slug_param_qv( $args, $request ) {
  $slugs = $request->get_param( 'slug' );

  // If the `slug` param was not even set, skip further processing.
  if( empty( $slugs ) )
    return $args;

  // Pull out hierarchical slugs into their own list.
  $nested_slugs = [];
  foreach( $slugs as $index => $slug ) {
    if( strpos( $slug, '/' ) !== false ) {
      $nested_slugs[] = $slug;
      unset( $slugs[ $index ] );
    }
  }

  if( count( $slugs ) ) {
    $args['post_name__in'] = $slugs;

    if( count( $nested_slugs ) ) {
      $args['wpse261645_compound_query'] = true;
      $args['post__in'] = array_map( 'url_to_postid', $nested_slugs );

      add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse261645_compound_query_where', 10, 2 );
    }
  }
  else {
    unset( $args['post_name__in'] );

    if( count( $nested_slugs ) === 1 )
      $args['pagename'] = $nested_slugs[0];
    elseif( count( $nested_slugs > 1 ) )
      $args['post__in'] = array_map( 'url_to_postid', $nested_slugs );
  }

  return $args;
}
add_filter( 'rest_page_query', 'wpse261645_remap_slug_param_qv', 10, 2 );

function wpse261645_compound_query_where( $where, $query ) {
  global $wpdb;

  if( ! isset( $query->query['wpse261645_compound_query'] ) )
    return $where;

  return preg_replace(
    "/ AND ({$wpdb->posts}.post_name IN \([^)]*\)) AND ({$wpdb->posts}.ID IN \([^)]*\))/",
    ' AND ($1 OR $2)',
    $where
  );
}
```

The logic above handles a number of different situations depending on the value of `slug`:

- Any number of flat slugs are mapped into the `post_name__in` QV as per normal.
- A single hierarchical slug will be mapped into the `pagename` QV, letting `WP_Query` natively handle the path resolution.
- A list of hierarchical slugs will be resolved via `url_to_postid()` and mapped into the `post__in` QV. The lookups add additional overhead.
- A list of intermixed hierarchical and flat slugs will be mapped into the `post__in` and `post_name__in` QVs respectively and the WHERE clause modified to OR these conditions instead of ANDing them. Hierarchical slugs will be resolved to IDs, adding additional overhead.

In summary, the most efficient queries are the product of passing `slug` as a single hierarchical slug, or any number of flat slugs in a list. Lists of hierarchical or intermixed slugs will result in additional overhead.

As an added benefit, this implementation also inherently facilitates explicitly requesting a top-level slug by including a `/`. E.g. `?slug=foobar` would return all posts with the slug `foobar` as per usual, but `?slug=/foobar` will return just the post with the slug `foobar` which has no parent.

---

## Use a HEAD Request to the Web Path

**This is a horrible dirty hack** that relies on conventions outside of the REST API - ones which may incur a substantial overhead and which [some sites may be prone to disabling](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211817/how-to-remove-rest-api-link-in-http-headers) to boot - **I strongly recommend against doing this**. Doubly so in any code intended for distribution; you will end up with a lot of unhappy users.

By default, WordPress returns a number of `Link` HTTP headers in responses to content requests, one of which being the REST route to the resource or collection corresponding to the content. As such it's possible to resolve any nested slug path to a REST resource within 2 requests by leveraging WordPress's frontend permalink routing:

```js
async function wpse261645_fetchPage( path ) {
  let uri = `/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/?slug=${path}`;

  if( path.includes( '/' ) ) {
    const web_res = await fetch( `/${path}`, { method: 'HEAD' } );
    const link_header = web_res.headers.get( 'Link' ).split( ', ' )
      .find( val => val.includes( ' rel="alternate"; type="application/json"' ) );

    uri = link_header.substring( 1, link_header.indexOf( '>' ) );
  }

  return fetch(
    uri,
    {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    }
  ).then( res => res.json() );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This adds a path parameter and adjusts the query being made on the request accordingly. The get_page_by_path function helps us retrieve the correct page in WP and we can then adjust the arguments sent to the query that runs on the /pages path in wp-json.

```
add_filter('rest_page_query', function ($args, $request){
  $path = $request->get_param('path');

  if (!empty($path)) {
    $pageByPath = get_page_by_path($path, OBJECT, 'page');

    // overwrite the page id with the page id by path
    $args['p'] = $pageByPath->ID;
  }

  return $args;
}, 10, 2);
```

Allowing you to request a specific sub page like this:

```
.../wp-json/wp/v2/pages?path=/pageslug/subpageslug/
```

Comment: This worked well for me on wp `5.8.x`

Answer (score 0):

We just ended up with fetching the page using the child-page slug:

```js
fetch(/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=child-page)
```

If there is a page and a child page with the same array, we could now loop through that array response and find any post that didn't have any parents:

```
.then(page => page.find(p => p.parent === 0) )
```

This is our parent page. In our case, that´s what we wanted. Else you could use that parent.id, to loop through the fetch response array to find the parents child.

Not the prettiest maybe, but no need for any custom API changes in WordPress.